# define entity relationships just with id in body json Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-restcontroller

I'm trying to manage all my entities through id in CRUD.

Let's say I have Lesion entity and Exam entity.

**AbstractEntity.java**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@MappedSuperclass
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class AbstractEntity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
  @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
  @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
  private String id;
}
```

**Lesion.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "lesion")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Lesion extends AbstractEntity {

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "lesion")
  private List<Exam> exams;
}
```

**Exam.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "exam")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Exam extends AbstractEntity {

  @ManyToOne
  public Lesion lesion;
}
```

I try to set relationship between lesion and exam through exam id list, like :
(imagine there are already 2 persisted exam with id `e1afa296-05fe-4bc4-9103-0f0bb6a5cedd` and `97353d31-64ce-40f7-87ef-deab435a2f7c`)

```
POST <url>/lesion 
body: 
{
  "exams": [
       "97353d31-64ce-40f7-87ef-deab435a2f7c",
       "e1afa296-05fe-4bc4-9103-0f0bb6a5cedd"
   ]
}
```

For now, the best I can do is :

```
POST <url>/lesion 
body: 
{
  "exams": [
       {"id": "97353d31-64ce-40f7-87ef-deab435a2f7c"},
       {"id": "e1afa296-05fe-4bc4-9103-0f0bb6a5cedd"}
   ]
}
```

and manually get the persisted objects corresponding to these ids and set them manually in lesion.
I'm sure there is a more automatic way through Jackson but I'm stuck.

Have you an idea ?

Thank you.

Comment: In the end, you have to fetch the `Exam` by id to set in Lesion right? Did you mean you just send id and auto attached lesion without fetching from database ?

Comment: yes exactly what I mean (at least I want the fetching part automatic). I think I need some special service written by me who take the fetch process. Like json filter or something like that

Comment: First of all automatic is not possible but you can make it automatic writing your own service.